# Can't use Alternate Credentials to Run Start-Job jobs on Jenkins with PowerShell Plugin

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, powershell-jobs

System: Windows Server 2012 R2 | PowerShell v4 | Jenkins v1.607 | 64-Bit Java Version 8u60

For whatever reason, I am able to login to the Windows server that Jenkins is running on, and execute the following code **without issues**:

```
Start-Job -Credential $Creds -ScriptBlock {Get-Process}
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Upon trying to execute the *same* code within a Jenkins job, utilizing the PowerShell plugin, with the same user credentials I was using in $Creds, **it fails without any helpful information.** Credentials have been verified. This is the error that I get:

```
    [localhost] The background process reported an error with the following message: .
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2100,PSSessionStateBroken
```

I used the [Resolve-Error function, as found here,](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/07/resolve-error.aspx) to try and get more information. Here was the output:

```
writeErrorStream      : True
PSMessageDetails      : 
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: The background process 
                        reported an error with the following message: .
TargetObject          : localhost
CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2100,PSSessionStateBroken
ErrorDetails          : [localhost] The background process reported an error with the following message: .
InvocationInfo        : 
ScriptStackTrace      : 
PipelineIterationInfo : {}


00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000


ErrorCode                   : 2100
TransportMessage            : 
ErrorRecord                 : The background process reported an error with the following message: .
StackTrace                  : 
WasThrownFromThrowStatement : False
Message                     : The background process reported an error with the following message: .
Data                        : {}
InnerException              : 
TargetSite                  : 
HelpLink                    : 
Source                      : 
HResult                     : -2146233087
```

Still no helpful information. I'm at a loss as to what may be the issue, and have no idea how to proceed.